# How to get minGW to find the path to compile and link correctly

Tags: c++, mingw

I am currently using Sams Teach yourself C++ in 24 Hours for my computer science class that starts in about a week and it told me to download minGW and then change the path variable to ;C: \MinGW\bin, which I did, but then when I attempted to compile and link the "program" it told me to create, it says no such file or directory. Does anyone know why it is saying this or how it can be fixed? I even put the file which is named motto.cpp into the bin file and it is still saying that it cannot be found.

Comment: If the book isn't required for your course, drop it and run. Download Visual Studio, instead. You shouldn't have to worry about things like this while learning.

Comment: it's not technically required but the professor sent us an email and said he HIGHLY RECOMMENDS the book, so i'm not going to go against what he says. also, the book says that visual studio can be used, but the directions are mostly with MinGW

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows 7? If so, try opening Start Menu, searching for "Variables" and select "Edit System Variables" then search for the button at the bottom "Environment variables..." and push it. Then select "new..." under "User variables for ", assign it a name and put the C:\MinGW\Bin path for the value. Press "OK" twice and try it from command line.

I am unsure if you are using a compiler IDE such as DevCPP or CodeBlocks, so I am assuming you are doing this from command line. If this is a compiler issue, try editing the compiler settings for include, bin and lib. Point them to the MinGW bin for bin and include for include etc...

Comment: I just tried that and it's still giving me the same error message, saying there is no file location.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you trying to compile from command line? If so, please paste what you are typing to compile your program.

Comment: I am using MinGW as a compiler. The book I am using says to type in g++ Motto.cpp -o Motto.exe and every time I try that it says "no such file or directory," which is why I'm thinking it could be an issue with the path, but I did it exactly the way the book told me to do and it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you are right, that sounds like a file path issue. Do you have MinGW installed in your C:\ drive? Like C:\MinGW? If you do, you need to type in CMD:
 PATH=C:\MinGW\bin
Bin is the directory which contains the g++.exe If you do not have MinGW installed there, type PATH=C:\path\to\mingw\bin or download the installer from mingw.org. 
Note: You need to type PATH=C:\... every time you open a new CMD shell. You can fix this by editing the system variables like I mentioned before.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you use an IDE, it is much easier and you don't have to compile from command line. I use one, and trust me it makes coding a lot easier. I recommend Code::Blocks which you can download from codeblocks.org

Comment: I did download codeblocks, it came on a disc that came with the book I have to use with my class, but it says to use MinGW for some reason, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Code::Blocks uses MinGW as its compiler. My guess would be that your guide wants you to learn how to compile from command line.